# How to get wpf window instance from winforms

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

After login I'm opening this Mainwindow

```
MainWindow window = new MainWindow();
```

and closing the Login window.

In the main window there is a windows form I'm initializing globally

```
Scanner form = new Scanner();
```

I'm hiding and showing this Scanner Winforms according to my need. I need to call a Mainwindow button click from Scanner.cs
If I try to do `MainWindow window = new MainWindow();` from Scanner.cs it will create a new Mainwindow, which I don't want to do.

These are all the references I found.

- [WPF Find window instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6145235/wpf-find-window-instance),
- [WPF - How do I get the MainWindow instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19647375/wpf-how-do-i-get-the-mainwindow-instance)
- [open wpf from winform throws object reference not set to an instance of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37935585/open-wpf-from-winform-throws-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line of code saved my day

```
((MainWindow)System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow).MainWindow_Btn_Click();
```

After closing the login I have used this code to set the MainWindow.

```
Application.Current.MainWindow = window;
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an event in the `Scanner` like `SomethingRequested`. In `MainWindow` subscribe to this event and do what you need.